# Can you let RoundhousE generate a script rather than executing it

Tags: database, database-versioning, roundhouse

Is there a way to get RoundhousE to generate a script file without executing it?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get the entire script executed, for example to give to a DBA for deployment to a restricted prod environment? 

If so, perhaps https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/GettingStarted#roundhouse-change-drop-folder will help (essentially the log of a migration), which you could get from a sucessful migration to your Staging environment for example. Perhaps @ferventcoder could comment?

Answer (score 1):

RoundhousE does not generate script files. It is only a migration engine.

If what instead you are asking about is in reference to one of the Refresh Database parts of RH, then why wouldn't you want it to execute?

If you are doing it correctly, you should be working off of a local database, testing that the script works.

Comment: Would https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/GettingStarted#roundhouse-change-drop-folder act as a depolyment script which you could pass to a DBA, for deployment in a restricuted prod environment perhaps? See my comment on the question.

Comment: Why would a DBA not run RH?  The alternative is that you just give him /her the scripts and let them run them by hand. But RH is meant to be run in all environments up to and including PROD. And by restricted PROD environment I am assuming you mean locked down. Keep in mind I worked in a highly restricted financial institution that had SOx concerns and 4 different auditors when we developed and used RH through all environments.

Comment: DBA's can be funny like that ;). Seriously though, good point, I'm not sure what I was thinking.